# Why did Heaviside eliminate the magnetic potential from Maxwell's Equations?

Tags: electromagnetism, history, maxwell-equations

Maxwell's original equations had magnetic potential, but Heaviside eliminated this variable. What was the reason for Heaviside's removal of the magnetic potential?

Comment: Maxwells original paper: http://rstl.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/155/459.full.pdf

Comment: Wikipedia's article on the history of maxwell's equations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Maxwell's_equations#A_Dynamical_Theory_of_the_Electromagnetic_Field

Comment: Heaviside's contributions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oliver_Heaviside#Innovations_and_discoveries

Comment: Thanks! Also please note that purely historical questions may be better suited to [history of science and mathematics stackexchange](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @BobBobby If you do end up deciding that HSM is a better home for this, I advise against cross-posting (not that I think you would; it's just a precaution). You can flag your question or otherwise get in contact with one of the Physics mods - they're quite friendly - and they may send it to HSM. Cross-posting, on the other hand, is messy for people on both sites trying to sort it out. Thanks!